# Issue using find()

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a function which creates posts in a database. The posts get their own unique _id but upon creation, also get an "owner_id", which is the id of the user that wrote the post.

I've got a function which displays all public posts perfectly fine, and it looks like this:

```
public function getPublicPosts()
{
    try
    {
        return $this->getCollection("posts")->find(array("privacy"=>0));
    }
    catch(MongoCursorException $e)
    {
        echo "Posts retrieval failed: ".print_r($e);
    }
}
```

so, likewise I wrote my function to retrieve a user's posts like this:

```
public function getUserPosts($user_id)
{
    try
    {
        return $this->getCollection("posts")->find(array("owner_id"=>$user_id));
    }
    catch(MongoCursorException $e)
    {
        echo "Posts retrieval failed: ".print_r($e);
    }
}
```

getPublicPosts works totally fine. However, getUserPosts returns an empty Mongo Cursor Object, even when the user's _id and the post's owner_id fields are an exact match. On the page which displays posts, I've done the following to be sure:

```
<?php
     foreach($public_posts as $post):
?>
<?php echo $post['owner_id']; ?><br/>
<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>
```

And this gives the following result for 2 posts:

> 4ffa66f7e3ed570f62000000
>   4ffa66f7e3ed570f62000000

So I'm really not sure what is going on here. I've noticed that in the database, when I am inserting a user's id, it comes up in the field value as

> owner_id  {"$oid": "4ffa66f7e3ed570f62000000"}

Perhaps this is the issue? It doesn't seem to be a problem when I access $posts['owner_id'] when displaying public posts. I don't know why this is happening as I am not setting owner_id to be an array at all, just a single value (the user's own unique _id)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I get the feeling that privacy is an int value (working perfectly fine with >= equations) and your ownerid is handled as a string.

But that is just a shot in the dark (also wondering)

Comment: Sort of on the right track there! Basically the problem was that when inserting the user's _id into the document, I needed to type it as a string, as I guess mongo _id's retrieved from the db are objects. So when inserting one again, it inserts {"$oid":"your id"} rather than just "your id".

Comment: It is called a `MongoId()` in PHP

Comment: to expand: for example, to find by _id: `$db->users->find(array('_id' => new MongoId($user_id)))` the driver will automatically translate `MongoId` into `ObjectId` for you.

Comment: Yes! I just found this out as well, thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to query the database for the document by using its _id using PHP is to use the following method as stated by @Sammaye above

```
$db->users->find(array('_id' => new MongoId($user_id)))
```